# 'php.ini' file creation on server

Tags: php

I am developing a PHP website, but I can’t see the *php.ini* file on my server. My host will not provide it.

So I'm now going to create a copy of that *php.ini* file.

So I have tried `system()`.

I searched in Google and I found *[Creating a custom php.ini using the server default php.ini and configuration settings](http://drupal.org/node/290592)*.

Here they are using it like this:

```
system("cp /usr/local/php5/lib/php.ini /home/YOURUSERNAME/php.ini");
```

On my server when I looked at the [phpinfo](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.phpinfo.php)(), my *php.ini* location is:

```
/ms/svc/php5/conf/php.ini
```

And when I looked for the current directory of my server using

```
$dir_path = str_replace( $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'], "", dirname(realpath(__FILE__)) ) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
```

I got my current directory as:

```
/netapp/whnas-swamp/s11/s11/01712/www.sample.com/webdocs/
```

So my system command will now look like this:

```
system("/ms/svc/php5/conf/php.ini  /netapp/whnas-swamp/s11/s11/01712/www.sample.com/webdocs/php.ini");
```

I have named this page *getthephpini.php*.

And when I browsed this page I got a blank page, but no new *php.ini* file created in my server.

Is any mistake in that code? What is the correct way?

Comment: Maybe if you explained WHY you need to see the installed php.ini someone could help you with an appropriate solution.

Comment: i want to change the upload file size in that php.ini file.

I have tried another ways like changinh .htaccess file, but it resulted in 500 internal server error.

and i have tried changing httpd file, but it has no effect.

now i'm trying to chage the php.ini file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is this command that lets you change the settings from within PHP code.

```
ini_set('upload_max_filesize', '64M');
```

Editing php.ini directly (even if you had access to it) would likely not have worked, because the web server would need to be restarted for the setting to take effect.

Answer (score 3):

A properly configured PHP installation will not give you physical access to php.ini from your PHP code.

What you are trying to do is not possible.

Comment: That begs the question if it possible to achieve the desired effect (increasing upload file size) using file `.htaccess` (usually enabled on that kind of hosting). Can you expand your answer to cover that?

Comment: @PeterMortensen This may be helpful https://www.a2hosting.com/kb/developer-corner/php/using-php-directives-in-custom-htaccess-files/setting-the-php-maximum-upload-file-size-in-an-htaccess-file